# Making a WordPress site accesible from inside LAN and outside it

Tags: wordpress, dns, router, lan

I configured WordPress on a PC inside my LAN. So I can access it from the same computer with localhost/WordPress or another pc on the LAN with IP/WordPress.

I configured the router so port 80 is redirected to the server IP, but if a page is loaded from outside my LAN, it fails to load CSS and JS as the route is localhost on WordPress config. If I change it to my freedns url, let's say: myamazingurl.mooo.com, it is accessible from outside my LAN and it loads CSS and JS.

Now I can't access my website from *inside* the LAN.
Is there any workaround or fix for that?

I read about dnsmasq but I didn't succeed.

Comment: What about using relative URLs? instead of `http://localhost/myfile.css` ==> `/myfile.css`

Comment: I think Wordpress uses a base url. So I don't know if it's possible. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option I found is to edit /etc/hosts file and redirect the freedns url to my localhost. So it's working now but I don't know if it's the right way of doing this...

Answer (score 3):

the main issue is because wordpress use the server address from database.

WordPress uses the root url from the option named `home` and `siteurl` so if you try access WordPress outside their computer it might get the incorrect path for css and javascript.

you need to change the options under `setting` -> `general` and fill in the `WordPress Address (URL)` and the `Site address (URL)` with your server IP

if you want to get correct path without doing redirect, you can defining the dynamic root url under `wp-config.php`

add this script below the `define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');`

```
/**
 * get home url from absolute path
 * @return string url to main site
 * hello@lafif.me
 */
function get_dynamic_home_url(){
    $base_dir  = ABSPATH; // Absolute path
    $doc_root  = preg_replace("!${_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']}$!", '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
    $base_url  = preg_replace("!^${doc_root}!", '', $base_dir);
    $protocol  = empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'http' : 'https';
    $port      = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
    $disp_port = ($protocol == 'http' && $port == 80 || $protocol == 'https' && $port == 443) ? '' : ":$port";
    $domain    = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    $home_url  = "${protocol}://${domain}${disp_port}${base_url}";

    return $home_url;
}
$url = get_dynamic_home_url();
define('WP_SITEURL', $url);
define('WP_HOME', $url);
```

Comment: The IP address method works well for me. No need to download anything.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Relative URL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/relative-url/) WordPress plugin. Even though the plugin is made for accessing the page via IP from local network, the effect should stay the same. (Because the main problem is the changing URL)

> Relative URL applies wp_make_link_relative function to links (posts, categories, pages and etc.) to convert them to relative URLs. Useful for developers when debugging local WordPress instance on a mobile device.

`http://localhost:8080/wp/2012/09/01/hello-world/` will be converted to `/wp/2012/09/01/hello-world/`

`http://localhost:8080/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/style.css` will be converted to `/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/style.css`

> Then after activating this plugin, you can simply access your local instance using http://192.168.0.1:8080/wp/ on your iPad or other mobile devices without having styles and navigation issue.

Answer (score 0):

After trying just about everything to sort out a WP dev and borking and unborking it, I finally found come across the above solution.
Relative URL plugin works a treat. Thanks for the tip ByteHamster:)

UPDATE: After testing this wasn't quite what I was looking for. Found a fix here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55239/cant-access-wp-site-over-wifi-network

Namely...

`define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );`

`// or`

`// define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/path_to_dir' );`

`define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );`

`// or`

`// define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/path_to_dir' ); //this is the one that fixed my issue.`

Now I can see the dev site in all it's glory on all devices on the LAN.

Answer (score 0):

```
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
  define('ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/');
}

/**
 * Function to get the home URL dynamically.
 *
 * @return string URL to the main site.
 */
function get_dynamic_home_url()
{
  $protocol = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? 'https' : 'http';
  $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
  $port = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']; // Get the port number

  // Include the port number in the URL if it's not the default for the protocol
  $port_suffix = ($protocol === 'http' && $port != 80) || ($protocol === 'https' && $port != 443) ? ":" . $port : "";

  $url = $protocol . '://' . $host . $port_suffix . '/your-site'; // Add '/your-site' to the URL

  return $url;
}



$url = get_dynamic_home_url();
define('WP_SITEURL', $url);
define('WP_HOME', $url);
```

Comment: edit `wp-config.php` to use Dynamic IP to visit wp site

add this script below the define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');